# Suggest code corrections in Idea

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've recently moved from Eclipse to Intellij IDEA for java development,

[image]

I have some code as shown in the screenshot, and as you can see there is no package called test2, Eclipse used to give suggestion if I want to create/move such a package, what is the IDEA equivalent shortcut for that option ?

Answer (score 1):

Context specific actions can be brought up by **alt+enter** while having your cursor on the underlined part.

May I also suggest **ctrl+shift+a**. This brings up a search field for all kinds of menu items and settings.

**Edit**

Two more tips I always give IntelliJ newcomers:

- Regularily check out Help/Productivity Guide. It tells you which features you don't use yet.
- Install the Key promoter plugin. It tells you which shortcuts you could have used when you use an IntelliJ-Feature.

Comment: Or click it with your mouse and search for the red light bulb, it will reveal the same context menu.

Comment: Added two more tips.